# Set emulator/device orientation programmatically in instrumentation test

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

In my instrumentation tests I want to test something in both landscape and portrait mode, so I'd like to set the orientation before the tests start. Is there a way to set the device or emulator orientation programmatically?

I am aware of the [`setRequestedOrientation()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setRequestedOrientation%28int%29) method but this works for a certain activity, if another activity is started I have to remember to call it again. What I'm looking for is a way to set the orientation "globally", so that every new activity is automatically started with that orientation.

UPDATE:

The solution must fit 2 requirements: 1) it **doesn't** make me change my production code, 2) it needs to run in a CI environment.

Comment: have you define orientation in Activity tag of your meanifeast?

Comment: @SanketKachhela Wouldn't that be the opposite of what he's asking?

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a ViewAction I created for making this simpler:
https://gist.github.com/nbarraille/03e8910dc1d415ed9740

The usage is described in the comments.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it for all of your activities by making a own AbtractActivity Class.

```
public abstract class AbstractActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
}
```

Now you have to inherit all your activities from this class.

Comment: I updated my question, please take a look. In my production code the activities doesn't have a fixed orientation, so I cannot do what you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can start two emulator simultaneously one in potrait mode and one in landscape mode. To change emulator orientation use ctrl + f12.