# run espresso androidTest s in Portrait and Landscape

Tags: android, android-espresso

what is a good way to run my test-suite in portrait and landscape mode? Is there already a way to do so or do I have to implement a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create `@Rule ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> myActivity`; you can perform something like this:

```
     myActivity.getActivity()
    .setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Answer (score 0):

By default Espresso doesn't support it, however you can add you're own ViewAction.

Add the class OrientationChangeAction to you're project and use it like below
https://gist.github.com/nbarraille/03e8910dc1d415ed9740

```
onView(isRoot()).perform(orientationLandscape());
onView(isRoot()).perform(orientationPortrait());
```

---

Found this solution within this comment;
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28949976